# Looking for a solution to display object detection results of live video using HTML

Tags: html, opencv, canvas, websocket, video-streaming

I'm looking for a effective way to add the bounding boxes to the live video displayed on a webpage.

The project is to detect the cars in the **video stream (1080p 30fps) captured by a camera using built-in rtsp function** and display the results at the webpage.

My current solution:

The frame image is extracted using OpenCV. I run the detection algorithms frame by frame in real time. The frame image is first compressed into JPEG and then encoded into a Base64 string. Then, the Base64 image string along with the bounding boxes is encapsulated into JSON. I transmit the JSON string to the frontend using WebSocket.

At the frontend, I use canvas to draw the frame image each time a message is received.

Now the problems are:

1. The compression progress JPEG(OpenCV imencode) + Base64 (base64.b64encode) takes too much time, the throughput is about **20FPS** (without detection).
2. The images displaying on the browser is slow and not smooth, the framerate **can not even achieve 20FPS** (without detection). And the webpage **takes much memory and may become not responding**.

I wonder if there is a solution to my problems **(achieve 30FPS)** or there are any other ways to achieve my purpose **(synchronize the backend detection results and the frontend live video)**.

P.S.
The bounding boxes are not rendered to the image at the backend because there may be some operations need to be done to the bounding boxes at the frontend, e.g., determing whether to show the bounding boxes or not.

EDIT: The codes in python (without detection) at the backend are like:

`Main.py`

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue    
import base64
import json
import cv2
import WSServer

def capture(path, outq):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    while True:
        ret, image = cap.read()
        outq.put(image)

def conv2jpg(inq, outq):
    while True:
        image = inq.get()
        imgEnc = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 75])[1].tostring()
        outq.put(imgEnc)

def conv2b64(inq, outq):
    while True:
        imgEnc = inq.get()
        strEnc = str(base64.b64encode(imgEnc), 'utf-8')
        outq.put(strEnc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # After arg parsing
    ws = WSServer.WSServer(args.ip, args.port)

    capQ = Queue(2)
    jpgQ = Queue(2)
    b64Q = Queue(2)

    capP = Process(target=capture, args=(args.input, capQ, )) 
    # args.input is the rtsp address of the camera
    jpgP = Process(target=conv2jpg, args=(capQ, jpgQ, ))
    b64P = Process(target=conv2b64, args=(jpgQ, b64Q, ))

    b64P.start()
    jpgP.start()
    capP.start()

    while True:
        strEnc = b64Q.get()

        msg = {'image': strEnc}
        msgJson = json.dumps(msg)

        # Send the json string over Websocket
        USERS = ws.getUSERS()            
        for user in USERS:
            user.put(msgJson)
```

`WSServer.py`

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
import asyncio
import websockets

class WSServer:
    def __init__(self, ip="localhost", port="11000", interval=1.0/60):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.interval = interval

        self.USERS = set()
        self.USERS_Lock = threading.Lock()
        self.P = threading.Thread(target=self.proc)
        self.P.setDaemon(True)
        self.P.start()

    async def get(self, q):
        if q.empty():
            return None
        return q.get()

    async def register(self, q):
        with self.USERS_Lock:
            self.USERS.add(q)

    async def unregister(self, q):
        with self.USERS_Lock:
            self.USERS.remove(q)

    async def serve(self, websocket, path):
        q = Queue()
        await self.register(q)
        try:
            while True:
                while True:
                    msg = await self.get(q)
                    if type(msg) == type(None):
                        break
                    await websocket.send(msg)
                await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)
        finally:
            await self.unregister(q)

    def getUSERS(self):
        with self.USERS_Lock:
            return self.USERS.copy()

    def proc(self):
        print('Listening...')   
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(self.serve, self.ip, self.port))
        loop.run_forever()
```

EDIT2: The simplified codes at the frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="myImg" style="display: None;"></img>
        <canvas id="myCanvas">
        <script>
            var img = document.getElementById('myImg')
            var cvs = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
            cvs.width = 1920
            cvs.height = 1080
            var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d')
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:11000/");
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                var msg = JSON.parse(event.data)
                img.src = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + msg.image
            };
            function render () {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
                window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
            }
            window.requestAnimationFrame(render)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know how you implemented it, since you did not share anything, but I had a friend that implement it redrawing the canvas for every image and that was the problem. I switched to changing the `src` of an `img` element in his code and everything was smooth. His use case was "running a game emulator on a browser" and we could play without any delay (45fps+) after this change.

Comment: Neither of your two 'questions' are questions, by the way.

Comment: For 1. Why do you even need this JPEG image? Simply pass the video stream to your front and from the bounding box generated by opencv, extract the image from the video. For 2. Not sure to get if you want to keep all these images in the page, but if so, you can't do much about it...

Comment: @Kaiido For 1. Each video frame has a group of bounding boxes representing the detection results. So passing the video stream to the frontend can not match the bounding boxes to the video frames.  For 2. Just display the current frame as playing a video.

Comment: Why that? You send the bounding-boxes, then grab the corresponding portion of the current frame from a canvas on which you draw the video directly.

Comment: @Kaiido The detection process takes some time, so the video frame displaying on the Web may not be the frame of the bounding boxes. The synchronization problem is why I have to send the frame image along with the corresponding bounding boxes.

Comment: No, you need a way to synchronize both your backend and your front videos. On a recorded video (as opposed to a stream), you could send the currentTime along with the bounding boxes info. Now, I'm not too sure what you mean by "live video" in your question, so there may be tons of different ways to tackle this issue. But sending the grabbed frames from the backend sounds like a terrible idea, when you [can do it so easily on front-end](https://jsfiddle.net/zwr036q9/)

Comment: @Kaiido The video stream is obtained by using built-in rtsp function of the camera. So is there any solution ？

Comment: @Berriel codes added. `img` is smoother but I have to draw rectangles on the image.

Comment: If you have an `img`, you should not need to draw rectangles on the image. You can draw the rectangles on a canvas and this canvas can be on top of the image. However, @Kaiido seems to know much more than me in this case. I'd go with his suggestions.